# ERROR trabajando con Linkedin - Android

Tags: android

Que tal a todos estoy comenzando a integrar una **app**, con **Linkedin** 
y estaba en ello..

```
public static final String HOST = "api.linkedin.com";
    public static final String TOPCARDURL = "https://" + HOST
            + "/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,public-profile-url,picture-url,email-address,picture-urls::(original))";

@OnClick(R.id.btnLinkedin)
    public void iniciarSesionLINKEDIN() {
        LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).init(this, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthSuccess() {
                getPerfilLinkedin();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
            }
        }, true);
    }

private void getPerfilLinkedin() {
        APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        apiHelper.getRequest(this, TOPCARDURL, new ApiListener() {
            @Override
            public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse s) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = s.getResponseDataAsJson();
                    Log.d(TAG, object.get("emailAddress").toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, object.get("formattedName").toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getPerfilLinkedin"+ error.toString());
            }
        });
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Logro abrir la pantalla de **Linkedin** pero se cierra de inmediato, el error ocurre que al hacer una sesion `iniciarSesionLINKEDIN()`, me vota de frente al `onAuthError()`
con el siguiente mensaje

```
11-10 15:33:15.241 18900-18900/application.ucweb.proyectoecoinca D/IniciarSesionActivity: {
                                                        "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST",
                                                        "errorMessage": "either bundle id or package name \/ hash are invalid, unknown, malformed" }
```

Si alguien ya a tenido experiencia al integrar **Linkedin** por favor me pueda dar una mano. Gracias.

Comment: El paquete de la aplicación en la consola  esta correctamente definido?

Comment: Hola si ahorita estoy deduciendo también eso.. pensé que debía copiar el código para obtener el hash pero acabó de ver que debe ser al proyecto el cual se debe utilizar, de todas formas gracias me aseguraste ver esa parte !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema reportado es :

> "errorMessage": "either bundle id or package name / hash are invalid,
>   unknown, malformed"

El package name de tu aplicación debe tener un error, asegura este correctamente escrito:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

El Key Hash debe ser obtenido a partir del Keystore usado y se debe definir el  respectivo Package Name.

```
PACKAGE_NAME,KEY_HASH
```

http://duladissa.blogspot.mx/2015/03/android-linkedin-sdk-100-usage.html

Comment: utilizo esto que me da LINKEDIN `keytool -exportcert -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` pero debo modificar keystore y sha, a los que tengo ?

Comment: El Keystore no lo debes modificar, el KEY HASH obtenido es el que debes agregar y el paquete de aplicación correcto. Recuerda que si publicas a la playstore, debes obtener el KEY HASH de tu Keystore con el que firmaras la aplicación a producción.

Comment: Yo tengo un hash de debug por que estoy empezando con un proyecto, entonces en el lado de configuración seguí toda la documentación hasta debug.. pero tengo ese problema. Y ps ahora dudo si es que es o no, del lado de configuración, por otro lado también me fije que decía que era obligatorio tener un hash de debug y release, es cierto ?

Comment: Si solo es para pruebas no es necesario, si vas a liberar el "Hash" de release es el que se obtiene del Keystore que usarias para firmar a release.

Comment: Me podrías ayudar por favor necesito acabar esto, y siento que es más q todo configuración y no programar del todo u.u; y si es así abras un chat, si no puedes lo comprenderé todos tenemos cosas que hacer.

Comment: @marlonpya estoy tratando me indica : This room might already exist. Tal vez es porque alguna vez me banearon jeje, solo puedo entrar al chat en español, puedes agregarlo y con gusto amigo!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48310/discussion-between-marlonpya-and-elenasys).